# overridePendingTransition and wallpaper

Tags: android, transition

I have two activities that use as style Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar and I'd like to animate their transition. I created 4 animation like this in 4 different xml files.

```
left_in.xml
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="200" />
```

[image]
This is a graphic about the problem:

pic A activity 1 is running

pic B activity 1 starts activity 2 and the transition works like a charm

pic C activity 2 is running;

pic D PROBLEM! the translation starts, but the wallpaper now seems to be anchored to activity 1. So I see activity 2 to disappear on a black background and activity 1 to appear with the wallpaper (the wallpaper is not just uncovered, it's translating).

I tested the same code on different device:
Acer Liquid E (android 2.3), Samsung S4 (4.3), HTC one (Cyanogen 11). The problem appears only with the samsung. Does anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I found what cause the problem. This issue seems to appear when an activity is marked as "singleTask".

This is what happened.

1. Activity1 starts Activity2.
2. Transition runs as expected.
3. Activity2 try to start Activity1 but this is not re-created, simply put in foreground.
4. Transition show the glitch.

I could not change the activity1 launchmode to "default", so I just added these flag when in activity2 I start activity1.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, activity1.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
```

This fixed the problem.